# The sign of a composition of permutation

Tags: permutations

Let $f, g \in S_n$
I am to proof the following theorem:
$$sgn(f\circ g) = sgn(f)\cdot sgn(g)$$
What I know is that
$$sgn(f) = (-1)^{I(f)}$$
Where $I(f)$ is the number of transposition in permutation $f$.
However I don't know how can the proof should look like.

Comment: Hint: write $f$ and $g$ as products of transpositions. Then write $f \circ g$ as a product of transpositions.

Comment: I thought about that. But I'm not sure how can I do that @kccu

Comment: Well you know that $f$ and $g$ *can* be written as products of transpositions, right? So suppose $f=\tau_1\cdots \tau_m$ and $g=\sigma_1\cdots \sigma_n$ where $\tau_i$ and $\sigma_i$ are transpositions. Do you see where to go from there?